# How to correctly modify the request headers when proxying a http request

Tags: node.js, axios, proxy

While building a simple Axios proxy logic I encounter an SSL error when copying the request headers into the new request.

If you do this, it works:

```
axios.post(remoteServerURL, originalRequest.body)
```

But as you can tell, this does not works as an true proxy since we are dropping the request headers, so I did this:

```
axios.post(remoteServerURL, originalRequest.body, { headers: originalRequest.headers })
```

That tho gives an error:

```
[ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID]: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: webhook.site. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:1inbox.biz
```

If I have to guess, It is relative to messing with the origin?. What is the correct way to pass the original headers to the new request? Keep in mind that I'm not trying to simulate that my proxy is the real origin, I just want to pass any *relevant* request headers from the source to the destination.

PS: I know there are libraries that do proxy servers, I just want to understand why this does not what and learn how to do it right.